# Upgrading Gradle version from 2.4 in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, libgdx

I have to start a work with libgdx to build simple game. I generated my project using libgdx-setup. I installed Eclipse for coding. I must upgrade my Gradle version from 2.4 to 2.6 or newer.

```
Support for builds using Gradle versions older than 2.6 was removed in tooling API version 5.0. You are currently using Gradle version 2.4. You should upgrade your Gradle build to use Gradle 2.6 or later.
```

I have tried [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/blob/master/README.md) for upgrade, but Eclipse still says same error.
Also i installed [Gradle manually](https://gradle.org/install/) with macOS & Linux guide because i'm using Eclipse on Debian 10 Buster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no find a solution, then i switched to Apache Netbeans 11.0 and installed Oracle JDK 12, opened my project and detected out-dated Gradle version then upgraded Gradle automatically without any problem, works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when updating to a newer Eclipse version. I found two separate references to the old gradle version in my project. Once I changed the reference in `build.gradle` to:

```
gradleVersion = '4.10.3'
```

and in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` to

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.3-bin.zip
```

I was able to go to the `Gradle` menu in the project's Eclipse context menu and choose `Refresh Gradle Project`. The problem was resolved after refresh.

Comment: Cool solution, worked for me!  Only I had to use https instead of http